# SAS-¿Como puedo usar el formato "DATETIME" en una condicional "IF"?

Tags: condiciones, sas

Ando llevando acabo el código de abajo  y necesito crear una condicional que me devuelva los registros con la fecha mas reciente (la cuál será cualquiera que sea igual o mayor a "08JUN20:0:0:0") en la tabla con nombre "tabla_1", La línea que me causa error es esta:

```
`if Fecha >= '08JUN20:0:0:0'dt.  then output tabla_1;`
```

Agradecería de mucho su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Tienes 2 opciones:

Por un lado, mirar el formato de la variable fecha, si es datetime20. tendrás que añadir ceros a la sentencia

```
if fecha >= '18Nov20:00:00:00'dt then output tabla_1
```

Pero soy mas partidiario de usar datepart:

```
if datepart(fecha) >= '18NOV20'd then output tabla_1
```

Además si tu dataset solo genera la tabla tabla_1 no sería necesario ponerlo en la sentencia, sería suficiente con:

```
data tabla_1;
set origen;
if datepart(fecha) >= '18Nov20'd then output;
run;
```

Saludos